# jenkins executor not building MasterToSlaveCallable

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

Trying to build a project in Jenkins
Some misconfiguration or something that has been broken , and cannot understand what.

The builds get executed but no command is printed on the Console Output.

It has to do with the executors. The jenkins log is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/security/MasterToSlaveCallable
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1138)
        at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:756)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1309)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1365)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.security.MasterToSlaveCallable
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
        at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 12 more
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates a likely incompatibility between a Jenkins plugin and either another plugin or Jenkins core. I would double-check the versions of core and your plugins on the Jenkins management page to make sure you're not running any incompatible versions.